# Download de arquivo extenso em website

Tags: html, download, áudio

Estou com o seguinte problema: Em um site que desenvolvi para um cliente, contém uma página para download de áudio, segue código para download do audio:

```
<a href="<?php print base_url(); ?>web_files/uploads/radio/<?php echo $audios->audio; ?>" download="<?php echo $audios->nome; ?>" target="_blank">
<button class="btn botoes_play_ouvir botao_saber_associacao">
<p>Baixar</p>
</button>
</a>
```

O problema é que, na página, contém uns 20 arquivos em formato de lista para download e os arquivos variam de 5 a 18MB.
Quando clico em download, o website fica processando, como se quisesse executar o áudio ao invés de já baixar.

Alguém teria alguma dica de como posso melhorar isto?

Caso queiram visualizar o problema, segue link do website: [Clique aqui](http://feapesc.org.br/radio)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode requisitar o download por JS é bem simples

Código `JavaScript`

```
function saveAs(url) {    
var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1).split("?")[0];
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.onload = function() {
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response);
a.download = filename; 
a.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
delete a;
};
xhr.open('GET', url);
xhr.send();
}
```

E aqui, para baixar o arquivo.

```
  <a href="javascript:" onclick="saveAs(<?php print base_url(); ?>web_files/uploads/radio/<?php echo $audios->audio; ?>)"><?php echo $audios->nome; ?></a>
```

Se não funcionar comente.

Comment: Show, só fiz uma pequena alteração. Irei mante-la na pergunta para visualização.

Answer (score 0):

Conforme solução do Victor Gomes, segue como ficou o código final:

```
<div onclick="saveAs('<?php print base_url(); ?>web_files/uploads/radio/<?php echo $audios->audio; ?>')">
   <button class="btn botoes_play_ouvir botao_saber_associacao">
      <p>Baixar</p>
   </button>
</div>
```

<sub><sup>Este código foi originalmente [postado pelo autor na pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/121486/revisions) como versão final da solução, portanto, convertido em resposta</sup></sub>